# centered margin text (with KOMA Script and Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, koma-script, marginpar

The following MWE sets some boxed texts on the margin:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\marginline{\tikz[baseline=(n.base)]\node[rounded corners,draw] (n) {200};}
\blindtext
\marginline{\tikz[baseline=(n.base)]\node[rounded corners,draw] (n) {demo};}
\blindtext
\marginline{\tikz[baseline=(n.base)]\node[rounded corners,draw] (n) {$(a,b)*(c,d)$};}
\end{document}
```

The margin texts are aligned to the left side. However, I would like to have the margin text centered and I'm looking for a solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can add `\centering` manually, redefine `\marginline` or define a new command:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}\show\marginline
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand\cmarginline[1]{% or \renewcommand\marginline[1]
  \marginpar[\centering {#1}]{\centering #1}%
}
\begin{document}
\cmarginline{\tikz[baseline=(n.base)]\node[rounded corners,draw] (n) {200};}
\blindtext
\cmarginline{\tikz[baseline=(n.base)]\node[rounded corners,draw] (n) {demo};}
\blindtext
\cmarginline{\tikz[baseline=(n.base)]\node[rounded corners,draw] (n) {$(a,b)*(c,d)$};}
\end{document}
```